# What does the notation $a\mid b$ mean? Does it mean the remainder of the divison is $0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

Does $a\mid b$ mean $a$ completely divides $b$ with remainder $0$ or it can partially divide with remainder belongs to any integer or a real number?

Comment: What is the question ? Definition of "$a|b$" ?

Comment: It means "divides with remainder $0$".

Comment: If an integer "divides" another this means that there is no remainder essentially by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $\mid$ is commonly used to denote the "divisibility relation" in the integers (or also some other structure).

Thus, indeed using your terminology $a\mid b$ means that the remainder of the division of $b$ by $a$ is $0$.

In other words this means that there is some *integer* $q$ such that $b=qa$.

This form is a more common way to define the relation: one says that for integers $a,b$ one has $a\mid b$ if there exists an integer $q$ such that $b=qa$.

In more advanced contexts one might replace the integers with some other structure and speak about divisibility in that structure with essentially the same definition.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the congratulations.